# Browse database tables inside Netbeans with transaction type JTA

Tags: jakarta-ee, derby

I'm currently learning about Java EE development. I've been using a persistence unit with transaction type RESOURCE_LOCAL up until now, and it was possible to browse the database tables inside Netbeans under the Services tab. I'm using the Derby database org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.

I had to change transaction type to JTA in order to get EJBs working, but now I can no longer see any tables from within Netbeans.

Can I fix this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

> I had to change transaction type to JTA in order to get EJBs working, but now I can no longer see any tables from within Netbeans.

This is very weird, to my knowledge, the "database explorer" of NetBeans and the `persistence.xml` are two completely unrelated things.

Anything special or noticeable to mention about the connection string? Can you ping the connection pool under GlassFish (you're using GlassFish, right?)? Are you using the derby server started by GlassFish or the one started by NetBeans? Could you describe the steps allowing to reproduce your issue?